# Unable to deserialize simple Json using ServiceStack serializer

Tags: json, serialization, servicestack

For some reason, this code is not working.
What I missing here? It is a simple class, and the Json is really basic.

```
using System;
using ServiceStack.Text;

namespace Test
{
  public class Boo
  {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
      return string.Format ("[Boo: id={0}, name={1}]", id, name);
    }
  }
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine ("{name: \"Superman\", id: 1}".FromJson<Boo>());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, I am running this under mono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keys are not strings. ServiceStack's serializer expects JSON to have the keys be valid JSON strings.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{\"name\":\"Superman\",\"id\":1}".FromJson<Boo>());
```

Not sure whether spacing matters, but I try to keep things as compact as possible.

Comment: Yep and the [json.org](http://www.json.org/) spec requires keys to be quoted strings. The fact that JavaScript object literals doesn't enforce quotes is why it's often confused with valid JSON, which does.